# CSS3 Transform Skew One Side

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to create "CSS3 Transform Skew One Side"

I found one solution, but it's not useful to me, because I need to use a image for background (not color)

```
#skewOneSide {
    border-bottom: 40px solid #FF0000;
    border-left: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Even this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hfkk7/4/) is not useful as well (skewed area should be transparent)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Try this:**

To *unskew* the image use a nested div for the image and give it the opposite skew value. So if you had 20deg on the parent then you can give the nested (image) div a skew value of -20deg.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parallelogram {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(20deg);
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/301/301);
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="parallelogram">
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The example:

http://jsfiddle.net/diegoh/mXLgF/1154/

Comment: @darthmaim's answer (below) to use a psuedo (before or after) to skew the inner border's should be the accepted answer.  No need for any extra wrapper elements.

Answer (score 35):

Maybe you want to use CSS "clip-path" (Works with transparency and background)

"clip-path" reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Generator: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Example:

```css
/* With percent */
.element-percent {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* With pixel */
.element-pixel {
  background: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 32px) 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* With background */
.element-background {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat center/cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 32px) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element-percent"></div>

<br />

<div class="element-pixel"></div>

<br />

<div class="element-background"></div>
```

Comment: This is by **far** the best way of going about this. Excellent demo; up-voted.

Answer (score 17):

you can make that using transform and transform origins.

Combining various transfroms gives similar result. I hope you find it helpful. :)
See these examples for simpler transforms. this has left point :

```css
div {    
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,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');
    -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    margin: 10px 90px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This has right skew point :

```css
div {    
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,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');
    -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    margin: 10px 90px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

what `transform: 0% 50%;` does is it sets the origin to vertical middle and horizontal left of the element. so the perspective is not visible at the left part of the image, so it looks flat. Perspective effect is there at the right part, so it looks slanted.

Comment: This distorts the image sadly

Comment: While this would be the perfect case for me as I don't care that much about content distortion, the issue is that is also affect the height of the div, the height is smaller than the 200 you assigned :(

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but I would like to suggest using a linear-gradient to achieve the same effect instead of margin offset. This is will maintain any content at its original place.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwXaf/2/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* reset */
ul, li, a {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
/* nav stuff */
ul, li, a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
/* appearance styling */
ul {
    /* hacks to make one side slant only */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, white, red);
}
li {
    background-color: red;
     transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-20deg);
}
li a {
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 80px;
     transform:skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform:skewX(20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You try with the `:before` was pretty close, the only thing you had to change was actually using skew instead of the borders: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfkk7/1101/

Edit: Your border approach would work too, the only thing you did wrong was having the before element on top of your div, so the transparent border wasnt showing. If you would have position the pseudo element to the left of your div, everything would have worked too: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfkk7/1102/

Comment: This is almost doing the job as i needed but here skewing also skews the background image, is there any fix for that. Anyhow added +1 thanks :)