# CSS create a box-shadow in diagonal

Tags: css, css-shapes

sorry for the weird title, I couldn't think of a better way to describe the issue

I've added a before element to my div to cut the side of it and I want to add a shadow over that div, but it looks weird because of the before element:

HTML:

```css
    #equipe1 {
      background: #262626;
      width: 564px;
      height: 121px;
      left: 0;
      top: 57px;
      position: absolute;
      box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #0c0c0c;
    }
    #equipe1:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      border-top: 130px solid #1a1a1a;
      border-left: 130px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      width: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="equipe1"></div>
```

and here's a JSFiddle showing the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/73t6uak0/

is there any way I could fix this to make the box-shadow go around the div or add an inset shadow to the before element?

Comment: how about using the after pseudo element?

Comment: it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the shadow to go around the div, right now, it looks like it's going around the before element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try perspective transforms to make the trapezium, without the need for pseudo-elements. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005217/4636773).

```css
body {
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
#equipe1 {
  background: #333;
  width: 564px;
  height: 121px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #AAA;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="equipe1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using the `skewX`transform:

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:-12%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transform:skewX(45deg);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px red;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```