# CSS - Oblique border without filling

Tags: html, css

I've a div and I need a border with the left side oblique, but I'm finding only solutions that have the element filled with color.
I need only the border, like this picture:

[image]

How can I do this?

My actual code:

HTML

```
<div class="arrow">
    <span id="time">30 mins</span>
    <img src="assets/up_arrow.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 35%;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
    border-color: #929A9D transparent #929A9D transparent;
 }

 .arrow > img {
     vertical-align: middle;
     width: 12px;
     height: 12px;
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cut Corners using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css)

Comment: Answer is here already, just add a border. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761202/css3-transform-skew-one-side

Comment: "Transparent cut out edge" doesn't resolve the problem, becouse border will disappear on the cutted edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more elegant way, that's more easier to maintain, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24691352/5287860.

New code:

```css
.row {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, transparent, #fff, #fff);
}
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #929A9D transparent #929A9D #929A9D;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    width: 100px;
}
.arrow > div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
}
.arrow > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="arrow">
        <div><span id="">30 mins</span></div>
        <img src="assets/up_arrow.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[TRY THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alfinpaul/5a7rhh0L/940/)

**HTML & CSS**

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:50px;

    color: #2E8DEF;

    border: 3px solid #2E8DEF;
    border-left:0;
}
#a:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -3px;
    left: -30px;
    z-index: -1;

    border:3px solid #2E8DEF;
    border-right: 0px;

    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="a">

    Hello

</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, the only problem could be that if my div is in a complex page, can be difficult to manage the css to always coincide the div.

Comment: thank you Nodiink, I think this has no complexity when u firstly created.

Answer (score 1):

**I have created the shape using border and before pseudo element. Hope this will help.**

```css
.ClassicBorder {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.ClassicBorder:before {
  height: 36px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  transform: skew(340deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(340deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(340deg);
  background: #fff;
  left: -9px;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ClassicBorder">
  30 Mins >
</div>
```

Comment: As the other answer (your solutions are very similar): great, the only problem could be that if my div is in a complex page, can be difficult to manage the css to always coincide the div.