# How to make pointed edge

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make interactive poster, but I have no idea how to make the squares to have pointed edges.

Please check out the image I attached!!

```js
$("body").mousemove(function(e) {
  var box = $("<div/>")
  box.css("top", e.pageY);
  box.css("left", e.pageX);
  box.css("background-color", "black");
  $("body").append(box);
  box.animate({
    height: "2000px",
    opacity: .0
  }, 2000, "swing");
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 5000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  opacity: .35;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include .js files here -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[So currently my code creates this visual effect,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGOSA.png)

[But I want the black squares to be pointed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHdJF.jpg)

[image: .]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 Transform Skew One Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761202/css3-transform-skew-one-side)

Comment: also, check out this site for CSS tricks like that: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the css arrow/triangle trick. Create a triangle instead of a rectangle:

Setting the div size to 0x0 and setting a big border, half transparent (bottom/right) and half black (top/left).

```js
$("body").mousemove(function(e) {
  var box = $("<div/>")
  box.css("top", e.pageY);
  box.css("left", e.pageX);
  $("body").append(box);
  box.animate({
    height: "2000px",
    opacity: .0
  }, 2000, "swing");
  
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 5000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: black;
  opacity: .35;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- include .js files here -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cool!! Thanks but is there any way I can get rid of the top triangle parts?

Comment: Updated my answer, try to remove this ` border-top-color: black;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `clip-path`

```
div {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 48%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 48%);
}
```

Customize the shape at https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: No when it stretched it becomes a line not a rectangle with a pointed edge

Comment: a thick line? How does it look

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: It should look like this

Comment: Are those black lines or black knife shapes?

Comment: Could you press the blue box saying Run code snippet to see how it works?